# Javadoc field comments with gson annotations

Tags: java, annotations, gson, javadoc

I am commenting some code I wrote. But ive hit a wall.

When commenting a field, it must be right before the field declaration, but I use GSON for serialization, with the @SerializedName annotation.

Now is the question, do I need to make the Javadoc comment before or after the annotation tag?

The code looks like this:

```
package Generic;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Address {

    @SerializedName(value = "name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName(value = "line1")
    public String line1;
    @SerializedName(value = "postCode")
    public String postCode;
    @SerializedName(value = "city")
    public String city;
    @SerializedName(value = "country")
    public String country;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter, but I prefer the before version:

```
/*
 * JAVADOC!!!
 */
@SerializedName(value = "name")
```

Comment: That is what I prefer myself to, but I thought, ask before breaking :)